# The authenticity of msg.sender variable in smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, verify, identity

We know that in a smart contract, `msg.sender` can be used to obtain the address of the user calling the contract. Is it possible for users to forge their own account addresses, causing the `msg.sender` variable we obtained in the smart contract to be not real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to fake `msg.sender`.

`msg.sender` will always be the sender (or caller) of the message.

Please do not confuse `msg.sender` with `tx.origin`. The latter will *always* be the EOA that initiated the call. The former *can* be the EOA that initiated the call, but can also be the address of a contract that made a `call` to another address within the transaction.